How to Solve This Integral About the Catenary Rotation Surface?
There is a equation $ x = a \cosh \frac{y}{a} $, and I want to get the surface area.
First, write:
\begin{align*}
 y = a \cosh^{-1} \frac{x}{a} 
\end{align*}
Then using integral is
\begin{align*}
 2\pi\int_1^2x\sqrt{1+\dot{y}^2} \ {\rm d}x
\end{align*}
my problem is
\begin{align*}
 A = 4 \pi \int_{a}^{x_{2}} x \sqrt{1 + a^{2} \left(\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x} \left(\cosh^{-1} \frac{x}{a}\right)\right)^{2}} \ {\rm d}x
\end{align*}
What an ugly integral. Did I do something wrong? How do I solve this integral?
Thanks by LiZ.

Do you know what $\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x} \left(\cosh^{-1} \frac{x}{a}\right)$ is equal to?

BTW what surface area do you need to find exactly? What is the axis of rotation?

@GReyes It is a problem about minimun surface of revolution, y axis, and use Euler equation can solve catenary.

Hint: $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\cosh^{-1} \frac xa\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-a}\;\sqrt{x+a}}$$
Can you solve the integral from here?
